# ARRAYFORMULA should be used only once in each formula or should it be used multiple times once for each need?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Sum the `VLOOKUP` results:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1:A,B1:C,2,FALSE))))
```

Sum two cells:

```
=(Z1+Z2)
```

Sum two specific values from `VLOOKUP`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(G1:G2,H1:I,2,FALSE))))
```

Now I need to come up with an average of the three results:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
    SUM(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1:A,B1:C,2,FALSE)))+
    (Z1+Z2)+
    SUM(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(G1:G2,H1:I,2,FALSE)))
)/3
```

But the faithful form would be:

```
=(
    ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1:A,B1:C,2,FALSE))))+
    (Z1+Z2)+
    ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(G1:G2,H1:I,2,FALSE))))
)/3
```

Both will reach the same result, my question is, what is the most correct and safe way from the standards of those who work professionally with Google Sheet?

1 → Use only one `ARRAYFORMULA` call for the all the formula.

2 → Use multiple `ARRAYFORMULA` calls, one for each specific need.

**Question reason:**

I still haven't found risks of using a single `ARRAYFORMULA` in the beginning and doing everything else within it like `=ARRAYFORMULA((...)+(...))` rather than `=ARRAYFORMULA(...)+ARRAYFORMULA(...)`, but I not finding risks doesn't mean they don't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One instance of `ArrayFormula` on the outside is both sufficient and the professional standard.

However, I must say that I don't understand your formula usage or intention from your posted example. You've got `+` between each element, which is redundant to `SUM`. And like `ArrayFormula`, you only need one outer `SUM` to sum all elements in your usage.

Comment: Hi @ErikTyler actually in each ```SUM+VLOOKUP``` he is summing the values not only one, I made a small example here for you to see: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Qn4MdxFSXUITMDqk5mBcB810t0q6YQkJwIfV-4N5B2c/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: If I didn't understand this specificity you said, please help me understand, it's important for my learning!

Comment: Seeing your sheet helps to understand context, and I have edited my post response to reflect what I see there. However, you still only need ONE instance of `SUM` with zero instances of `+` (which are redundant to `SUM`). I added a new sheet to your sample spreadsheet. I hope you will enjoy learning a little by studying the comparisons there.

Comment: Perfect additions to the spreadsheet, will help me shorten the formulas I currently have a lot!